# How can I wait until the ajax processing receives data from the web server before handling success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Please forgive my poor English skills.
This message was written with the help of ChatGPT, but please understand that I may not be able to identify any errors in the message.

I am trying to receive JSON data from the node.js express web server through AJAX. However, since it takes about 1 to 2 minutes to acquire and edit the JSON data, I want to wait for AJAX processing until the web server completes this processing and returns a response to AJAX.

Therefore, I tried to use "done," but the defined processing in "done" is being executed before the response is returned, causing abnormal processing. I also tried changing "async" to false, but it did not work.

This processing is similar to a loading screen that waits for a response from the server. I have implemented all the functions that make the loading screen disappear and display the screen based on the processing results on the web page, but I am currently unable to receive data via AJAX as mentioned.

and i tried convert done to success

this my sample code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/simpleAchive/dataUpdate",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: 'type=' + param,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (res, status, xhr) {
        success();
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("error");
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('.hidden.running > .refresh_img').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
        $('.hidden.running').removeClass('running');
    }
});
```

If there is any appropriate sample or information to implement this feature, please let me know. Thank you.

======================================================

i solved this problem!
i dont use promise in my node.js web server project.
retry with promise.then~~, my ajax request can wait response!

my ajax request had nothing problem, my node.js project had a problem!
thanks for all of answer and comments!
very very thanks!

Comment: now i think, problem is my node.js web server process...
check my code now

Comment: Can you add the `jqXHR` and `textStatus` parameters to the `complete` function and then do `console.log(textStatus)` and see what it prints out?

Comment: Make sure you set the `timeout` property to a high value to account for the extremely long response time. Also, what is the reason it is taking 1 to 2 minutes to respond? That seems awfully slow for a web request. Maybe you need to optimize your server code to be more efficient.

Comment: that reason is other service api calling delay.
i need to get many different data from api.
in test request, that process taking 1 to 2 minutes.
thanks to your advice. i will try that.

Comment: oh, i misread your first comment mike!
i try make right response in node.js web server now...
after try this, i will try your suggest! thank you!

Comment: Is there a way that you can query the API server to get all of the data in fewer requests?

Comment: i want find get all of the data in fewer requests, but there is not existed.
that api is 'steam web api', i want detail data of user owned game, and user detail archievements.
detail achievements of each game is need one by one request.
if you have good idea, please let em know.

and, i solved my problem!
this is my first time of node.js project for study, i didn't know detail about  'promise'
now, my project use promise, and my ajax request wait return of promise!
thanks you for your help!

Comment: sorry mike...
i really can't english... i try my best, but you could be in a bad mood.
but i really thank you for your help!
i got a hint from your comments!

Comment: Maybe the translator is not really translating correctly, but no, I'm not in a bad mood. I apologize if I came off that way.

Comment: I was just worried if you were offended. Have a nice day, thank you